# No 64bit virtualization in virtualbox (Intel S1200RP motherboard + Xeon 1270 v3)

Tags: linux, 64-bit, debian, virtualbox, virtualization

i have a server, it works on Intel S1200RP mother board and CPU is Xeon 1270 v3.
I've installed msr-tools and rdmsr 0x3A returns me 5, it mean that 64bit virtualization enabled in Bios.
Same time i have VirtualBox 4.3.6 + extpack on debian 7x64.
Virtual machines have configuration:

```
--chipset ich9
--acpi on --ioapic on
```

And i still can't launch 64bit operation system on virtual machine, it tells me that CPU (virtual cpu) didn't support this.

How can i check, is it bad configuration of virtualbox (installed via apt-get + extpack from website) or it's bad BIOS firmware (but why in this case rdmsr returns me 5)? Before i used another server (it was intel 4770 CPU and simple MB and all worked well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in VirtualBox.
It's neccesary to use longmode

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <vmname> --longmode on
```

OR to select correct ostype (64-bit).

For virtuall machine. Now all is works well \m/